# Facebook login button custom text changing after logout

Tags: facebook

I have application where i have put custom text "Connect". on fb-login button but after fb logout. it gets changed to "Log In" rather than "Connect".

Connect

any resolution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FB.getLoginStatus to set the button InnerText to Connect or Log In which ever you want...